# Update row NULL values with fields from another row

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to update any NULL values in a row, with values from another row, which are linked through a different table. The idea is to update the initial value to have any extra information from the other. I've made this environment to show what I want to happen.

test_data:

```
id    value
------------
1     null
2     null
3     TEST
```

test_alt:

```
id1    id2
------------
1     2
1     3
```

This is the query I've been unsuccessfully using:

```
UPDATE test_data AS A
INNER JOIN test_alt ON A.id=test_alt.id1
INNER JOIN test_data AS B ON test_alt.id2=B.id
SET A.value = IF(A.value IS NULL, B.value, A.value);
```

Wanted outcome for test_data:

```
id    value
------------
1     TEST
2     null
3     TEST
```

Outcome after query:

```
id    value
------------
1     null
2     null
3     TEST
```

Should of been mentioned initially: I need to grab any not null value (it doesn't matter which), therefore an answer has been reached.

Comment: Unsuccesful how?

Comment: Is there any way of establishing that 3 is the most recent id2 in test_Alt? (such as an auto_increment id column or date)

Comment: You don't have to JOIN twice.. One JOIN between test_data and test_alt should do the trick.

Comment: @RaymondNijland he actualy does need to join twice..

Comment: "he actualy does need to join twice" No @sagi `UPDATE test_data 
INNER JOIN test_alt 
ON test_data.id = test_alt.id1
SET test_data.value = 'TEST'
WHERE test_data.value IS NULL; ` works just fine -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44de5e/1

Comment: That is not what he wants..

Comment: Edited the questions to show current output, there is no way of establishing 3 as the most recent, but as long as it updates when there is a non null value available, then it's working correctly. If there was another value "TEST2" connected to id 1, I wouldn't mind if it updated to TEST or TEST2.

Comment: For each null value, he has to find the matching `ID` inside the `test_alt` table , and then fetch its matching `value` from `test_data`

Comment: "That is not what he wants." Then his wanted expected output in the question is wrong `Wanted outcome for test_data:

id    value
------------
1     TEST
2     null
3     TEST` @sagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't care which non null values is selected then you could join and limit for example

```
drop table if exists test_data,test_Alt;
create table test_data( id int, value varchar(100));
insert into test_data values
(1  ,   null),
(2  ,   null),
(3  ,   'TEST'),
(4  ,   'anotherTEST');

create table test_alt(id1 int,   id2 int);
insert into test_alt values
(1  ,   2),
(1  ,   3),
(1  ,   4);

update test_data t 
join (
select id1,value
from test_alt
join test_data on id2 = id
where value is not null
order by value asc limit 1
) s on s.id1 = t.id 
set t.value = s.value
;

select * from test_data;

+------+-------------+
| id   | value       |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | anotherTEST |
|    2 | NULL        |
|    3 | TEST        |
|    4 | anotherTEST |
+------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This will work, apologies for the lack of information initially, my first time!

Comment: "This will work, apologies for the lack of information initially, my first time! " Now i finally understand what you was after @TomaszChrost No problem next time try to make better expected output then you can get much better help.

Comment: I should of placed two not null values in the example, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
UPDATE test_data a
SET a.value = (SELECT b.value FROM test_alt c JOIN test_data b ON(c.id2 = b.id) 
               WHERE a.id = c.id1)
WHERE a.value IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm getting: #1093 - Table 'a' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data - Will work with this suggestion and see if it helps, thank you.

Comment: What happens if `SELECT b.value FROM test_alt c JOIN test_data b ON(c.id2 = b.id) 
               WHERE a.id = c.id1` matches more then one record.. Then the query will fail.

Comment: And there's my issue. Stupid mistake, thanks for the help!

Comment: "I see I didn't fully understand the question as well." no problem @sagi the topicstarter question and comment causes convision to say the least.. I also made a answer attempt which i geuss it's not what the topicstarter needs.

Comment: @TomaszChrost What do you mean? Have you managed to get the query to work ?

Comment: The query was as RaymondNijland stated, failing. After being pushed for information P.Salmon returned an answer which would answer my question, and updated the initial question to reflect the missing information.